# Populate dropdown based on row values one time

Tags: php, mysql, date, populate

Hey guys I have a table that I built, but I am trying to add some stuff into it. I want to have a dropdown gets populated based on the dates that are in the database.

This is how my db looks:

http:// i.imgur.com/YKgjf4C.png

I want it to show the dates from pat_date a single time and only the ones that are in the database, skipping the ones that aren't there, and limiting the so called duplicates it to 1 date per line, bascially not listing like 07/11/2013 about 14 times.

```
_________________
| SELECT DATE |v|
-----------------
|  07/02/2013 | |
|  07/08/2013 | |
|  07/11/2013 | |
--------------| |
```

How am I able to do this with my current script?

Right now I have it like this

http:// i.imgur.com/r0zCrDj.png

but its annoying going through every date, and instead would be easier if i could already have the dates with a dropbox i know has some people scheduled on it.

How is this possible?

Comment: Please don't use imgur pictures, they really don't help much

Comment: How does it not help? It goes a general idea and how my database looks.

Comment: questions should be self contained and not link to external locations, there is no guarantee that they will be available at a latter date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a distinct query

```
SELECT distinct `date` from `yourtable`;
```

I would also suggest you storing your dates as a date field, this will make sorting and manipulating based on those values much easier.

Comment: Thanks man, I based my code off of that. 

`SELECT distinct pat_date from patients ORDER BY pat_date DESC`

Comment: One last thing, when I select a date a do LOOKUP, although the correct data is displayed, the selection jums pack to latest date – it should stay with what I selected last. 
                                                    
`<select name="exam_date" id="type" class="neutral">

<?php 
$sql_gdate = "SELECT distinct pat_date from patients ORDER BY pat_date DESC";
$result_gdate = mysql_query($sql_gdate);
while($row_gdate= mysql_fetch_assoc($result_gdate)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row_gdate['pat_date'].'">'.$row_gdate['pat_date'].'</option>';
}
?>

</select>`